# Fetching Azure Datafactory pipelines run details

Tags: python, azure

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=secret, tenant=tenant)
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
run_response = adf_client.pipelines.create_run(rg_name, df_name, pipeline_nm,{})
# Monitor the pipeline run
pipeline_run = adf_client.pipeline_runs.get(rg_name, df_name, run_response.run_id)
while (pipeline_run.status == 'InProgress' or pipeline_run.status == 'Queued'):
#print("[INFO]:Pipeline run status: {}".format(pipeline_run.status))
time.sleep(statuschecktime)
pipeline_run = adf_client.pipeline_runs.get(rg_name, df_name, run_response.run_id)
print("[INFO]:Pipeline run status: {}".format(pipeline_run.status))
print('')

```
        activity_runs_paged = list(adf_client.activity_runs.list_by_pipeline_run(rg_name, df_name, pipeline_run.run_id, datetime.now() - timedelta(1), datetime.now() + timedelta(1)))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you are running?  It would be helpful to see the actual code to understand the context of where the method calls you are mentioning are.

Comment: When I'm trying to run: list(adf_client.activity_runs.list_by_pipeline_run(rg_name, df_name, pipeline_run.run_id, datetime.now() - timedelta(1), datetime.now() + timedelta(1)))  Im getting error 'ActivityRunsOperations' object has no attribute 'list_by_pipeline_run'. How can I resolve this.

Comment: Can you follow my complete steps? And could you edit your question to readable?

Answer (score 8):

Activity run is different from the pipeline run, if you want to fetch the pipelines run details, follow the steps below.

1.[Register an application with Azure AD and create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal)

2.[Get tenant and app ID values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [Create a new application secret and save it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret)

3.Navigate to the datafactory in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` ->  `Add role assignment` -> add your application as a role e.g. `Contributor`, details follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

4.Install the packages.

```
pip install azure-mgmt-resource
pip install azure-mgmt-datafactory
```

5.Then use the code below to query pipeline runs in the factory based on input filter conditions.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

subscription_id = "<subscription-id>"
rg_name = "<resource-group-name>"
df_name = "<datafactory-name>"

tenant_id = "<tenant-id>"
client_id = "<application-id (i.e client id)>"
client_secret = "<client-secret>"

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=client_secret, tenant=tenant_id)
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)


filter_params = RunFilterParameters(last_updated_after=datetime.now() - timedelta(1), last_updated_before=datetime.now() + timedelta(1))
pipeline_runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(resource_group_name=rg_name, factory_name=df_name, filter_parameters = filter_params)

for pipeline_run in pipeline_runs.value:
    print(pipeline_run)
```

[image]

You can also get the specific pipeline run with the `Run ID`.

```
specific_pipeline_run = adf_client.pipeline_runs.get(resource_group_name=rg_name,factory_name=df_name,run_id= "xxxxxxxx")
print(specific_pipeline_run)
```

[image]

Comment: How can this be modified to get triggered runs?

Comment: how do we use the continuation token here? @JoyWang-MSFT